# vue router.push Uncaught (in promise) undefined

Tags: vuejs2

I try to redirect to another route if user is logged in, but got this error.
Please help me!

```
Uncaught (in promise) undefined
```

I used JWT for authentication.

**jwtLogin**

```
loginJWT({commit}, payload) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        jwt.login(payload.userDetails.email, payload.userDetails.password)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.data.user_data) {
                    router.push(router.currentRoute.query.to || '/')
                    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.data.access_token)

                    commit('updateUserInfo', response.data.user_data, {root: true})

                    commit('setBearer', response.data.access_token)

                    resolve(response)
                } else {
                    reject({message: 'Wrong Email or Password'})
                }

            })
            .catch(error => {
                reject(error)
            })
    })
},
```

After clicking the login button and reloading the page, then click the login button again, there are no errors.

An error occurs if the page is not refreshed after clicking the login button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error, cause you didn't handle the promise error.

Promises, if not handled well, can cause unpredictable errors (especially when mixed with unnecessary callback functions, which is not the case here).

I see two bigger mistakes in your code:

- the starting promise error/success is not handled *(unhandled/uncaught promise error)*
- you navigate away before/during the user login data is saved *(router.push())*

Both of them can throw you an error, even if you think you are already logged in.

Also, the if/then condition is not necessary inside promise chain, it can handle itself if done right.

Hopefully this *pseudo* code will help you better understand:

```
login(formdata)
  .then((response) => {
    // login response success,
    // save the userdata and token
    resolve(response) // or return(respone)
  })
  .then((response) => {
    // user data succesfully saved,
    // and you can do extra check on it
    // safe to navigate away
    resolve(reponse) // or return(respone)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // anything goes bad,
    // you land here with error message
    // handle the error
  })
  .finally(() => {
    // if finally() is supported by your login method
    // you can decide whats next,
    // the promise is fulfilled/rejected
  })

// other potential (and often made mistake) to do logic here:
// we are 'after' the login method, but not out of the woods yet
// the promise might be still be unresolved/unrejected = undefined
```

There are other ways to handle promises: *async/await*, *try/catch*
But I prefer to chain it, when the method is *'thenable'*.
More elegant IMHO

Happy promises!